# Error in converting SageMaker XGBoost model to ONNX model

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, onnx

I'm trying to convert a SageMaker XGBoost model to ONNX, in order to use the ONNX model in .Net application using ML.NET. I've tried to convert the model using `winmltools` and `onnxmltools` but both tools are returned similar error.

There is a good resource to use machine learning in business area. I've tried [Using Machine Learning to Improve Sales](http://fasttrackteam.com/using-machine-learning-to-improve-sales-a-simple-example.aspx) in SageMaker to create the model and then convert the model to ONNX model. The example is working well in SageMaker.

[image]

After running the example, I got a model and the type of the model is `sagemaker.estimator.Estimator`. I've tried to convert the model by using `winmltools` and `onnxmltools`. But both are returned same error.

`ValueError: No proper operator name found for '<class 'sagemaker.estimator.Estimator'>'`

[image]

I've tried to follow [Convert ML models to ONNX with WinMLTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/convert-model-winmltools) and [ONNXMLTools enables conversion of models to ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools) to convert the SageMaker model to ONNX model.

After that, I used `xgb.create_model()` command to create SageMaker model. Then used the tools to convert the model to ONNX. but no luck. I got same error this time. Just the model is different.

`ValueError: No proper operator name found for '<class 'sagemaker.model.Model'>'`

[image]

Then I load the model using `pickle` and tried to convert the model. I got same error, just the model is different.

`ValueError: No proper operator name found for '<class 'xgboost.core.Booster'>'`

[image]

At this moment, I have no idea about the issues. How should I solve the issues. I've attached the [Improve Sales Classification to ONNX notebook file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An4yDE4xkdIjhOMgu_vBDiYa8VPrgQ?e=r6muMO) for reference.
Could you please take a look at the issues and let me know a way to solve the issues?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try loading the model from the file using the XGBRegressor class (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.load_model)?

Comment: @Guy yes, I tried that. Please check the attached image for details.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Trl2hPKFY1PqCOp6xaNnpJZors8GP8SV

Comment: Please note that, the model is loaded successfully but conversion is not worked.

Comment: The error in the image is talking about payment_date not int. What is payment_date in your features and how did you encode it for the xgboost modelling?